# C++, treating dates as numbers

Tags: c++, date

Is there a way to treat dates as numbers, without the need of implementing my own class for that?

I would like to compare dates, compute differences (Monday - Friday should be one day, I'm considering business days)  etc..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As chris suggested, use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/date_time.html) or, if that's a problem, use the C library ([ctime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_date_and_time_functions) header in C++).

Comment: would it be possible to know whether two days belong to the same week or not (I'm considering business days only)?

Comment: I don't know if there is a "same_week" function, but it will be easy enough to write one. For example using ctime, once you have the dates in tm format
   { bool same_week = (t1.tm_yday - t1.tm_wday) == (t2.tm_yday - t2.tm_wday); }

Comment: I see Boost Date provides week_number, so it is even easier.